# How to change utc_offset for timezone in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, offset

In my country, We don't have time change since 2023 March 21 like old in previous years.
I changed server timezone on Asia/Tehran (+0330).

And now we have the problem of saving the time in the database. And the hours are stored in the database with one hour ahead.

How to change `utc_offset` for **Asia/Tehran** in PostgreSQL?. I want to change the offset from +0430 to +0330 And never change. This data are in `pg_timezone_names` table but can not change this table.

[image]

Executing update query on this table, has below error:

```
update pg_timezone_names set utc_offset = '03:30:00' where name = 'Asia/Tehran';
```

> ERROR:  cannot update view "pg_timezone_names" DETAIL:  Views that do
> not select from a single table or view are not automatically
> updatable.
> HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF
> UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your time zone database. Find out if you are using the operating system's copy or if PostgreSQL uses its own copy. Run

```bash
pg_config --configure
```

If the output contains `--with-system-tzdata`, you are using the operating system's time zone database.

To fix the problem, upgrade the appropriate software – either the operating system or PostgreSQL.

Comment: output: `'--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo'`. And My server timezone is Asia/Tehran(+330).

Comment: Then you have to update your operating system (or at least the time zone database).

Comment: I updated timezone in my server (CentOS 7) to my desired tz (Asia/Tehran +330). If postgres read tz from system, it should be ok but it is not. postgres still on +440 . I couldn't change tz in postgres.